# How to cast css cals() to rem?

Tags: css, css-calc

Is possible cast result of css calc operation to rem unit?

I'm trying to make this operation: `calc((100% - 2.3rem)/2)` and I need result to be in rem unit.

Comment: Well, did you tested it?

Comment: I don't understand _why_ you want to do this. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Its working here https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/9dc8ao36/

Comment: I've got in my application button to resize all fonts sizes. I need calcculate some divs height and this divs shoud change height if font size changed. This is why I need calc result in rem unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convert your `px` result to `rem` by using calc**

> 1 rem = 16 px

so use `/16` in your calc

```css
#rem{
width: calc(((100% - 2.3rem)/2)/16);
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="rem">hello</div>
```

**OR**

> 1 px = 0.0625 rem

```css
#rem{
width: calc(((100% - 2.3rem)/2)*0.0625 );
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="rem">hello</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: A rem is not always 16px. Most browsers(if not all) have it set as default, but users can alternate this.

Comment: Yes, users can alternate this. But because the default is 16px, doing the math with 16px creates the ratios accordingly. The result is that if someone changes the default font size, everything scales relatively to that size, creating a zoom-like effect on the text. That's the main reason to use rems in the first place.